# Quarkus Authentication using HTTP Request

Tags: authentication, request, postman, quarkus, form-data

I am pretty new into Quarkus world. I want to create a simple form authentication with Quarkus security.
Is there a way to do the authentication using a form-data with a POST Request from Postman?

Comment: I managed to create the authentication mecanism using Kerim's answer. The hard stuff was that I couldn't find which was the endpoint I need to send POST request in order to authenticate. For those who need, the endpoint is "j_security_check"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there could be many ways of authentication. For instance follow this tutorial for Basic Authentication check with a JDBC connection to a database:

[Using Security with JDBC](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-jdbc)

It explains how Quarkus can authenticate endpoints with the credentials stored in given database. You can use different types of databases.